# why selenium web driver does not have a GUI?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I saw selenium IDE has a GUI. but why selenium web driver and selenium RC don't have a GUI. I am asking this question, because I am trying to develop a UI automation system by using selenium web driver with a GUI?

Comment: selenium is a library. you can create your own framework with the small pieces it provides. having some kind of gui would be quite restricting - just like the selenium ide. once you spend some time with selenium, you will see that the ide is quite useless unfortunately for real tests - it might be somewhat useful for absolute beginners, but after an hour it only takes up space. a real useful gui would have thousands of controls (thus eliminating the restrictions), making it quite hard to use.

Comment: skandigraun can you please give me a example for why giving a GUI for selenium web driver is not a good idea?

Comment: Check the [javadoc](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/). To have a useful gui, it would be good to have ALL these classes and methods to be represented on the GUI (okay, maybe except for the abstract ones, interfaces and such). Still, it's 500+ classes, countless amount of methods, and their possible values... Who would use such a thing? Or who would use something that is not supported fully?

Answer (score 0):

remember selenium is a free (open source) automated testing suite so that have diferent tools for automate, in this case selenium web driver lets you automate web applications through the "webDriver", so that is not neccessary a UI for it. Here I attach you an image explaining all selenium test suite and its evolution

[Selenium test suite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S9QK.png)